# How to calculate signal to noise ratio in frequency domain with given cutoff frequency?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am pretty new to signal processing and I want to calculate the signal to noise ratio (SNR) from a signal in frequency domain.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create signal in time domain
N = 1000
T = 0.05
x = np.linspace(0, N*T, N)
y = 10 * np.sin(0.1 * np.pi * x)

noise = 2* np.random.normal(size=len(x))
y += noise

# signal in frequency domain
N = len(y)
x_f = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, d=T)
y_f = np.fft.rfft(y)
# normalize
x_f = x_f / max(x_f)
y_f = np.abs(y_f) / max(np.abs(y_f))
```

The idea is to use a cutoff frequency (e.g. 0.3) to divide the signal in a useful signal (left side) and noise signal (right side) and calculate the SNR. But how can I accomplish this and is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in different ways, depending on the characteristics of the signal and the accuracy required. In your case, you can see a clear peak of the useful signal in the spectrum; for real signals, the useful signal might not be so clearly distinguishable from the noise in its spectrum.

By analysing the normalised spectrum of the signal, you can perform a simple filtering based on an esperimentally chosen amplitude threshold. You can take it as 0.2, for example.

```
threshold = 0.2
y_f_filtered = y_f.copy()
y_f_filtered[y_f < threshold] = 0
```

After returning to the time domain, you can calculate signal-to-noise ratio using the formula:

```
y_filtered = np.fft.irfft(y_f_filtered)
signal_power = np.sum(y ** 2)
noise_power = np.sum((y - y_filtered) ** 2)
snr_db = 10 * np.log10(signal_power / noise_power)
```